# Using a conditional operator with .labelStyle throws error

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to make it so when isTextVisible is false then the .labelStyle modifier will show label title and icon but .iconOnly when true. However it causes an error in the parent Form view "Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'FormStyleConfiguration' that does not accept a closure" and doesn't give me a specific error for the modifier.

```
Import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var text = ""
    @State private var isTextVisible: Bool = false

    var body: some View {

        HStack {
            Button {
                withAnimation {
                    isTextVisible.toggle()
                    text = ""
                }
            } label: {
            Label(isTextVisible ? "Delete" : "Add", systemImage: isTextVisible ? "minus.circle.fill" : "plus.circle.fill")
                .labelStyle(isTextVisible ? .iconOnly : .titleAndIcon) // throws exception
                .symbolRenderingMode(.palette)
                .foregroundStyle(.white, isTextVisible ? .red : .green)
            }
            if isTextVisible {
                TextField("", text: $text)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you posted is irrelevant. The actual errors are
`Member 'titleAndIcon' in 'IconOnlyLabelStyle' produces result of type 'TitleAndIconLabelStyle', but context expects 'IconOnlyLabelStyle'` and `Static property 'titleAndIcon' requires the types 'IconOnlyLabelStyle' and 'TitleAndIconLabelStyle' be equivalent`.

This means that IconOnlyLabelStyle and TitleAndIconLabelStyle are incompatible so you can't put them in a condition like that. So the ideal way to achieve this would be two have 2 labels and switch between them based on the condition like so:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = ""
    @State private var isTextVisible: Bool = false

    var body: some View {

        HStack {
            Button {
                withAnimation {
                    isTextVisible.toggle()
                    text = ""
                }
            } label: {
                Group {
                    if isTextVisible {
                        Label("Delete", systemImage: "minus.circle.fill")
                            .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                    }
                    else {
                        Label("Add", systemImage: "plus.circle.fill")
                            .labelStyle(.titleAndIcon)
                    }
                }
                .symbolRenderingMode(.palette)
                .foregroundStyle(.white, isTextVisible ? .red : .green)
            
            if isTextVisible {
                TextField("", text: $text)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, that they are two distinct types. I come up with another solution that is a custom ViewModifier that returns a labelStyle depending on the boolean but I think your answer is simpler if I use it in a custom TextField view.

Comment: Oh yeah a custom ViewModifier is also a nice solution. Glad I could help!